# How to send protobuf using jmeter?

Tags: apache, http, jmeter, protocol-buffers

I saved some binary files of serialized protobuf. I want to send them to my apache server using jmeter. I there any way to define a folder which jmeter will read the binary files and send each one as http request?

Comment: I don't believe there is built in functionality to use a folder, and cycle through all the contained files. But you can use a csv of all filenames as your input. see http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config for how to use csv files as data.

Comment: I have use custom sample to send these. So there was a jar that could provided needed files which was used in the java sample.